# Python Pandas drop columns not found in both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, intersection

**Problem Setup**:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'D': {0: 'D0', 1: 'D1', 2: 'D2', 3: 'D3'}, 'B': {0: 'B0', 1: 'B1', 2: 'B2', 3: 'B3'}, 'A': {0: 'A0', 1: 'A1', 2: 'A2', 3: 'A3'}, 'C': {0: 'C0', 1: 'C1', 2: 'C2', 3: 'C3'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E': {4: 'B4', 5: 'B5', 6: 'B6', 7: 'B7'}, 'D': {4: 'C4', 5: 'C5', 6: 'C6', 7: 'C7'}, 'F': {4: 'D4', 5: 'D5', 6: 'D6', 7: 'D7'}, 'C': {4: 'A4', 5: 'A5', 6: 'A6', 7: 'A7'}})
```

df1

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3
```

df2

```
    C   D   E   F
4  A4  C4  B4  D4
5  A5  C5  B5  D5
6  A6  C6  B6  D6
7  A7  C7  B7  D7
```

I'm trying to determine the best way to return a dataframe that contains ONLY columns that appear in 2 OTHER dataframes.

I've come up with a solution but it's problematic because it will drop `any` column that has `NaN`.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

     A    B   C   D    E    F
0   A0   B0  C0  D0  NaN  NaN
1   A1   B1  C1  D1  NaN  NaN
2   A2   B2  C2  D2  NaN  NaN
3   A3   B3  C3  D3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  A4  C4   B4   D4
5  NaN  NaN  A5  C5   B5   D5
6  NaN  NaN  A6  C6   B6   D6
7  NaN  NaN  A7  C7   B7   D7

df3 = df3.dropna(axis=1)

#This is the correct result I'm going for
    C   D
0  C0  D0
1  C1  D1
2  C2  D2
3  C3  D3
4  A4  C4
5  A5  C5
6  A6  C6
7  A7  C7
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).dropna(axis=1)
```

I have a feeling there's an easier way to return a dataframe containing only the columns that are found in both two different dataframes (columns intersection).  More elegant approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')
```

Comment: Here I am asking how to intersect and in `pd.concat`, there it is, join by `inner`.  I can't believe I missed that.  I like the fact that this is a simple one-liner.

Comment: @Jarad Don't beat yourself up :)  Also, please accept the answer if it's satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html#pandas.Index.intersection) of the 2 df columns:

```
In [177]:

cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
cols
Out[177]:
Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
In [178]:

pd.concat([df1[cols],df2[cols]])
Out[178]:
    C   D
0  C0  D0
1  C1  D1
2  C2  D2
3  C3  D3
4  A4  C4
5  A5  C5
6  A6  C6
7  A7  C7
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `columns.intersection()`. Your example makes perfect sense.  I know there's multiple ways to solve a problem but  would you prefer your answer over @chishaku of `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')` ?  Just curious if one approach has limitations that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Depends if you need to know the common cols upfront or not, the other answer is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
common_columns = list(set(df1.columns) & set(df2.columns))
pd.concat([df1, df2])[common_columns]
```

Result:

```
    C   D
0  C0  D0
1  C1  D1
2  C2  D2
3  C3  D3
4  A4  C4
5  A5  C5
6  A6  C6
7  A7  C7
```